# Visual Studio 2015 keeps changing document's tabs order. How to stop it?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How to prevent VS2015 from changing tab order when clicking on them? I set the order of the tabs by dragging them, then whenever I open any of them the order is changed automatically, how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, tabs order shouldn't change when clicking on a tab. Maybe you have Custom Document Well installed as a part of Productivity Power Tools with **Most recently used** sorting turned on:

[image]

In this case turn it off.

Comment: Am using vs 2017 and it was already turned off , and am still having this issue , what worked for me , is just turn off any kind of sorting (by project , alphabetically ...)